# How to use sscanf in C++ when data lines have different valid formats?

Tags: c++, scanf

How to sscanf a string in this format: name id str1 num1 str2  num2

Notes:

- if str1 = "NO" then num1 has a value,
- if str1 = "YES" then num1 hasn't a value

Example 1: Ali 1 **NO** 200  NO 100

Example 2: Ali 1 **YES** NO 100

```
char name [10];
char str1 [4];
char str2 [4];
int id, num1, num2;

 sscanf(inputString, "%s %d %s %d %s %d",
                            name,  &id, str1, &num1, str2, &num2 );
```

When str1="YES", I have a problem that str2 didn't take its correct value!!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 2 has not the same format as example 1, and here comes the problem. You could split the sscanf in 2 parts, and check if str1 is yes or not.

Answer (score 4):

Change to:

```
char str1 [4];
char str2 [4];
```

To allow 3 characters plus a NULL terminator.

Comment: well, this is just an example i put to explain the idea but in my code, i used the max string length

Comment: @alsadi90 In that case, I think Paul92's answer is more on track

Comment: This is only a minor part of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

When reading input into character arrays you should **always** specify the amount of available space! The default behavior for reading into a character array is to **not** impose any limit. This is clearly the wrong default as it makes buffer over-runs quite like.

In addition, when reading data you should **always** verify that read operation was actually successful: your second line doesn't match the format you are reading! After `YES` an integer is expected according to the format. That is, you want

```
if (6 == sscanf(inputString, "%10s %d %3s %d %3s %d",
                name, &id, str1, num1, str2, num2)) {
    // process the input upon success
}
```

Personally I would, of course, rather use an `std::istringstream`:

```
if (std::istringstream(inputString) >> std::setw(10) >> name >> id
        >> std::setw(3) >> str1 >> num1 >> std::setw(3) >> str2 >> num2) {
    // process the input upon success
}
```

To deal with optional values it would be reasonably easy to create a suitable `conditional` type and create a suitable input operator, e.g.:

```
template <int Size>
struct conditional_t {
    char* buffer;
    int*  value;
    conditional_t(char* buffer, int& value): buffer(buffer), value(&value) {}
};
template <int Size>
conditional_t<Size> conditional(char (&buffer)[Size], int& value) {
    return conditional_t<Size>(buffer, value);
}
template <int Size>
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, conditional_t<Size> value) {
    if (in >> std::setw(Size) >> value.buffer && !strcmp(buffer, "NO")) {
        in >> *value.value;
    }
    return in;
}

// ...
if (std::istringstream(inputStream) >> std::skipws >> conditional(name, id)
        >> conditional(str1, num1) >> conditional(str2, num2)) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd think this is quite sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably do the job in a single call to `sscanf()`.  You have to adapt to the value found in the third column.  Therefore, you need to do something like this:

```
char name [10];
char str1 [4];
char str2 [4];
int id, num1, num2;
int offset;

// %n conversion specifications do not count towards the return value
if (sscanf(inputString, "%9s %d %3s %n", name, &id, str1, &offset) != 3)
    ...report problem...
else
{
    if (strcmp(str1, "YES") == 0)
    {
        num1 = 0;  // Or other appropriate value
        if (sscanf(inputString+offset, "%3s %d", &str2, &num2) != 2)
            ...report problem...
    }
    else
    {
        if (sscanf(inputString+offset, "%d %3s %d", &num1, &str2, &num2) != 3)
            ...report problem...
    }
}
```

The `%n` conversion reports on the offset in the string where it appears.  It is not counted towards the return value from `sscanf()`.

You say you have many variations to deal with.  Maybe your input format is not well designed, or maybe you need a more complex system to identify the different formats for the data and which one applies.